# Prove that all the roots of $\sin z = a$, where $-1 \leq a \leq 1$, are real.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having a hard time to understand this. Is this saying, that $z$ is real whenever $a$ is between -1 and 1? If so, would I go about tackling it like so:

$\sin z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} = a$. Hence, $e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = 2a$... but then I struggle as to where to go from there. How would I approach this?

Comment: Set $w = e^{it}$ and solve the quadratic equation. Oh, and you forgot an $i$ in the denominator for the sine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Put $w=e^{iz}$ (so that $e^{-iz} = \frac1w$). This will turn your equation into a quadratic equation: $w^2 - 1 = 2iaw$. See if you can take it from there.

(Note: there is an $i$ missing in your formula.)

Comment: Aha, so when I apply to quadratic formula, I get $ia \pm \sqrt{a^2-1}$, so, if we focus on the positive first, $ia + \sqrt{a^2-1}$, then we get $-ia = \sqrt{a^2-1} \implies -a^2 = a^2-1 \implies a = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Not quite. You're not solving for $a$, but $w$ (and eventually $z$). What does the fact that $-1 \le a \le 1$ tell you? It looks like you have a sign error in your solution as well.

Comment: Well, in regards to $\sqrt{a^2-1}$, we will always be taking the square root of a negative number, unless $a = \pm 1$

Comment: You get $w = ia \pm \sqrt{1-a^2}$, and since $-1 \le a \le 1$, the $\sqrt{1-a^2}$ is real. Compute the modulus of $w$ for the quickest way to the goal.

Comment: Ah, yes, my math was incorrect, I see it now. Then, $|w| = \sqrt{a^2 + (\pm \sqrt{1-a^2})^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + 1 - a^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$. Thus, $|e^{iz}| = 1$. Does this mean the significance lies in $|e^{iz}| - \frac{1}{|e^{iz}|} = 0$? More importantly, with disregard to the value of a, we will always have a modulus of 1. Apologies, I'm still trying to decipher the significance of all these complex variable concepts.

Comment: $|e^z|=1$ if and only if $z$ is purely imaginary. Show this using the definition of $e^z$ if you don't already know it.

Comment: Okay, I see that. Does this imply that $|e^{iz}|$ =1 if and only if z is purely real? This could be shown by $i(x+iy) = xi-y$, in which now $x$, the originally real portion, is imaginary, and if we represent $xi - y$ as the complex number $p$, then we get $e^p$. For us, $|e^p| = 1$ as shown, and because this is 1, then $|e^p|$ is purely imaginary, which means indeed that $|e^{iz}| = 1$ if and only if z is purely real. Is this logic correct?